# Exclude html from search results (image names, etc.)?

Tags: search

We are heavily marking up our pages/posts so there is a lot of html and pictures being used.  The problem is that our search results are hitting image names and class names (maybe I have a few other examples but these are the two worst offenders).

Anyway to only search on the text showing on the page?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to try and alter the search SQL query. There's a filter for that.

```
$search = apply_filters_ref_array( 'posts_search', array( $search, &$this ) );
```

and (sidenote) a filter to influence the `ORDER BY` clause as well

```
$search_orderby = apply_filters( 'posts_search_orderby', $search_orderby, $this );
```

---

I haven't taken a look at search for quite some time, but when I look at `WP_Query::parse_search`, I could find something that might be of interest and worth giving a try.

1. Look at

   ```
   protected function parse_search( &$q ) {
   ```

   which has the full stack of Query variables in it, so everything added actually lands inside that function. And in there is the following line:

   ```
   $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';
   ```

   If `$q['exact']` is emtpy, then `$n` will be empty as well. This is what happens next:

   ```
   if ( $n )
       $q['search_orderby_title'][] = "$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$term%'";
   ```

   and

   ```
   $search .= "{$searchand}(($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}'))";
   ```

   So if you have a query var(?) named `exact` which needs to be `TRUE`, you should be able to just run *exact* matches instead of the default `LIKE` clause followed by *every* match that is in the middle of anything.
2. And as it's `protected`, it may get overridden by an `extend`ing class. So you could just go and create `class My_Search_Query extends WP_Query` and define your own internals to generate the needed SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses a simple MySQL `LIKE` search for the Core search feature. You can see that by running a simple test case like this:

```
$q = new WP_Query(array('s' => 'test'));
var_dump($q->request);
die;
```

You should see something like (Formatted courtesy of http://sqlformat.org/):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS dev_posts.ID
FROM dev_posts
WHERE 1=1
  AND (((dev_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%')
        OR (dev_posts.post_content LIKE '%test%')))
  AND (dev_posts.post_password = '')
  AND dev_posts.post_type IN ('post',
                              'page',
                              'attachment',
                              'book')
  AND (dev_posts.post_status = 'publish')
ORDER BY dev_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%' DESC, dev_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

You could filter  the `WHERE` clause with the [`posts_search` filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2484) but MySQL's `REGEX` is very limited. I doubt you will be able to get it to ignore markup.

If I were facing this problem, I would parse the post on save-- `save_post` or `draft_to_publish` for example-- and store a keyword list to the database, then use the `posts_search` filter, and/or other filters, to alter the search so that it searches the keyword list. Implementation can be more or less complicated depending on how you do it, but I think that is about the only way you are going to get the results you want without having to depend on MySQL extensions or external search engines like Sphinx.